# TRIAC broke (literally) – why?

Tags: ac, triac, attiny

I have built a circuit according to [Dimming 230V AC with Arduino](http://alfadex.com/2014/02/dimming-230v-ac-with-arduino-2/), with two output channels. The basic principle is:

- An ATtiny does zero detection via an optocoupler; when AC crosses 0 V, it triggers an interrupt.
- After a certain delay (e.g. pi/2), the ATtiny fires the TRIAC for [phase cutting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-fired_controller).

The Triac is a [BT136-600E](https://www.mouser.ch/datasheet/2/848/bt136-600e-1520534.pdf) with an I<sub>RMS</sub> = 4 A and I<sub>peak</sub> = 25 A.

We have connected four (not seven, as originally written) 35 W halogen lamps to each output. This is about 500 mA when they are all on.

When testing it with one lamp, the circuit worked as desired. With all 4 lamps, one Triac simply broke apart. Why/how can this happen?

### Measurements

*The measurements below are always with a single 28 W halogen bulb.*

After the comments, I have built a new board with a [BTA316-600D](http://www.ween-semi.com/sites/default/files/2018-10/bta316-600d.pdf) which stands 16 A rms. It is now attached to an [Aavid 5297 heatsink](https://www.mouser.ch/ProductDetail/532-529702B25G) which can dissipate 14 W of heat at ambient temperature of 45 °C, which is the maximum power dissipation of the BTA316 at 12 A.

The halogen lamps have a cold filament resistance of 136 Ω (measured with the Ohm meter), which would result in 1.7 A (rms) flowing through the filament of each lamp while it is cold, as opposed to 120 mA when it is hot.

To measure how much current is really flowing and when, I started with a 0.5 Ω 3 W shunt in series to the halogen lamp. The current flowing through the halogen lamp would then be calculated by the voltage drop across the shunt resistor.

Trying to measure the voltage drop with a [Picoscope](https://www.picotech.com/oscilloscope/2000/picoscope-2000-specifications) failed because, as I then learned, the ground reference of the scope probe is connected to the case ground and thus also to the USB wire ground and my Laptop ground and finally the power plug ground, which triggered the [RCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residual-current_device) fast enough to prevent additional harm.

The next attempt was to use one probe on each side of the resitor, this time with a [Rigol DS1054Z](https://int.rigolna.com/products/digital-oscilloscopes/1000z/#ds1000Z/ds1054z/) which can measure 230 V AC. However, the measurements turned out to be too imprecise and too low-res to measure mV differences at the 230 V range. The delay of the voltage difference is a bit odd too.

[image: Triac measurements]

I had the opportunity to get some measurements with a current clamp (yellow) and a differencial probe (green) connected to a [Keysight 4000 X](https://www.keysight.com/en/pcx-x205209/infiniivision-4000-x-series-oscilloscopes). Here, the measurements while the dimmer was active were as expected. The current stayed below 1 A while ramping up. However, when just turning on AC power (with a power cable with built-in switch, as used for turning lamps on and off), we measured peaks up to 10 A during < 200 ns.

[image: Triac measurements]

While this gives some insight into what is happening, it does not answer the question for me. The current flowing through the Triac while ramping up is relatively low. The peak when turning on AC is weird (why does it occur?), but very short as well.

This is the schema:

[image: Dimmer schema]

### Pictures

[image: Tricac split in two parts]

A close-up of the triac, the two parts bent apart for better visibility.

[image]

Comment: that breakage is because it exploded. Did you take into account that to achieve that 4A RMS, you need to supply sufficient cooling? What does the data sheet say about thermal resistance (in °C/W)? Estimate how much power is converted to heat within the TRIAC and thus how much hotter the device gets.

Comment: Your 1 A "all on" current measurement is for hot filaments. Measure the cold filament resistance of a single lamp and add it into your question along with the turn-on current calculation. It might answer the question.

Comment: Can you ramp up the fireing angle slowly?

Comment: @Transistor I will do some measurements as soon as the board is repaired, shunt has arrived already.

Comment: I meant that you should measure the filament resistance on a cold lamp using your multimeter. Then use that to calculate the switch-on current for one lamp and for seven and see how that matches the triac specifications.

Comment: @Transistor Ah. Got it. It is 136 Ω for a similar lamp, which is 1.7 A per lamp and 12 A for seven. That is indeed a bit above the rated 4 A …

Comment: @winny This is actually what I am doing, it ramps up over 4 seconds (if the load is not too high, at least).

Comment: @MarcusMüller Not taken into account. I am now considering the [BTA316-600D](http://www.ween-semi.com/sites/default/files/2018-10/bta316-600d.pdf) with 16 A RMS, the data sheet states that power dissipation is up to 20 W at 16 A. That would probably require a lot more cooling than the TO220 case can provide? (If I'm not mistaken, with an ambient temperature of 40 °C and Tmax = 100 °C and Rth = 60 K/W, it could only dissipate 1 W in free air …)

Comment: What's your dI/dt and snubber situation?

Comment: You can extend filament lamp life by ramping up the power gradually on turn on. It avoids the cold surge current and by the time you get to full power the filament is close to operating temperature. I had house reflector spotlamps on a dmmer switch and they always lasted years due to the soft start.

Comment: @winny I do not understand what you are saying, could you explain a bit what dI/dt and snubber situations are?

Comment: @marcus-müller I have added measurements to the question and a heatsink to the board.

Comment: See here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/285826/how-to-calculate-snubber-value-for-triac. dI/dt is the time derivative of the current which I hope you learned about in school.